# how to add symbol in a string on bash

Tags: string, bash, symbols

In a bash script i'm using command:

```
branch=git branch --contains 86cf181ec0df06656e57c7787866087592
```

output:

```
branch1 branch2 branch3
```

In next step i'm using command:

```
list_of_commits=$(git rev-list 86cf181ec0df06656e57c7787866087592 $branch --first-parent | tail -n 1)
```

but argument $branch must be written ^branch1 ^branch2 ^branch3 from $branch and full command:

```
list_of_commits=$(git rev-list 86cf181ec0df06656e57c7787866087592 ^branch1 ^branch2 ^branch3 --first-parent | tail -n 1)
```

How i can to add symbol ^ before every output words in argument $branch in my script?

Comment: Try \ to escape the character (as in \^branch2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the records and prepend the `^`:

```
$ d="hello i am muzzy"
$ echo "$d" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) {$i="^"$i} print}'
^hello ^i ^am ^muzzy
```

Also with `awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) $i="^"$i}1' <<< "$d"` taking advantage of `1`, that triggers the printing of the full record, and using [here-strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

or if you want to save it in a new var:

```
$ new_d=$(echo "$d" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) {$i="^"$i} print}')
$ echo "$new_d"
^hello ^i ^am ^muzzy
```

In your case,

```
branch=$(echo "$branch" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) {$i="^"$i} print}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use arrays with special parameter expansions instead:

```
branch=($(git branch --contains 86cf181ec0df06656e57c7787866087592))
list_of_commits=$(git rev-list 86cf181ec0df06656e57c7787866087592 "${branch[@]/#/^}" --first-parent | tail -n 1)
```